# How to write this SQL statement in DQL (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, dql

I have several approach, but because of complexity of the sql query.
I have installed and used JSON_GET_TEXT: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Postgresql\JsonGetText
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Postgresql\JsonExtractPath

but to no avail because of the nature of the json

```
select * from workshop_session where author -> 0 ->> 'id' = '2'
```

```
{author: 
      [
       {"id": 2, "email": "example@example.com"}, 
{"id": 3, "email": "example2@example.com"}
      ]
}
```

The GOAL is to use the json field key i.e. id in a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is wrong as it only checks the first element from an array of json objects.

---

You should use the `jsonb` type instead of `json` if you need to use keys in conditions. To get the desired result change the column type to `jsonb` , doctrine ORM supports it very well. And use `jsonb_path_exists` function in your `WHERE` clause.

```
select * FROM workshop_session WHERE jsonb_path_exists(author, '$[*].id ? (@ == 3)')
```

[Demo DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf614adf01dfd890d34886a446e93aaa) . This query will return sessions where author id = 3

---

`$[*].id` - path to id value in your jsonb object array